# update using case when condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd need to update a table if a condition is met, in my case: (select count(title) as title from posts group by title) > 1.

This is my query that doesn't work and I can't figured out what to do.

```
UPDATE posts SET text= CASE
WHEN (select count(title) as title from posts group by title) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
END
WHERE id <=8;
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you have a `group by` in a scalar subquery.  This results in multiple rows for a scalar subquery, which should result in an error.  I don't know the layout of the tables, but perhaps you want to use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE posts p
    SET text = (CASE WHEN (select count(title) from posts p2 where p.title = p2.title) > 1
                     THEN 'Y'
                     ELSE 'N'
                END)
    WHERE id <= 8;
```

EDIT:

You can also express this query using `join`:

```
UPDATE posts p join
       (select title, count(*) as cnt
        from posts p
        group by title
       ) pt
       on p.title = pt.title
   set  p.test = (case when cnt > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end)
   where id <= 8
```

Comment: Please take note to check the answer if Sir Gordon gave you the right answer.

Answer (score -4):

In the sub query use group by as you are using count function

Comment: They are using GROUP BY already, and that actually doesn't help there. All they needed in that particular situation was correlation with the main statement (UPDATE).